# convert MongoDB Rest's Guid into C# CLR

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I use mongodb with Rest. Every document is composed of a field Id(Guid) and Name (string)

Here's what's displayed when I access the webpage :

```
"_id" : { "$binary" : "Oq4RFClrRUOtIp89AQTGPw==",
        "$type" : "03"
"name" : "HelloWorld"
```

In mongodb, my Guid was transformed into a UUID (say my JMongoBrowser) and is displayed as 46eb229f-b493-5630-b0d7-aa00499fafa0.

But when I access my rest webpage, It's cutted in two parts (a binary, and a type). So how can I cast it into C# object ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string is a base-64 encoded string representing the guid's byte array, but you need to deal with byte UUD encoding, so you can have it back like this:

```
public static Guid ToGuid(string jsonUuid)
{
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(jsonUuid);
    byte[] rbytes = new byte[16];
    rbytes[0] = bytes[4];
    rbytes[1] = bytes[5];
    rbytes[2] = bytes[6];
    rbytes[3] = bytes[7];
    rbytes[4] = bytes[2];
    rbytes[5] = bytes[3];
    rbytes[6] = bytes[0];
    rbytes[7] = bytes[1];
    rbytes[8] = bytes[15];
    rbytes[9] = bytes[14];
    rbytes[10] = bytes[13];
    rbytes[11] = bytes[12];
    rbytes[12] = bytes[11];
    rbytes[13] = bytes[10];
    rbytes[14] = bytes[9];
    rbytes[15] = bytes[8];
    return new Guid(rbytes);
}
```

or like this:

```
public static Guid ToGuid(string jsonUuid)
{ 
    return new Guid(Convert.FromBase64String(jsonUuid));
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. The Guid I get is not the same. I tried jDZDtw+bSUu/TJ9JAKpwug== and should get 4b499b0f-b743-368c-ba70-aa00499f4cbf but I have b743368c-9b0f-4b49-bf4c-9f4900aa70ba
According to http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON yeah, it's base64 indeed

Comment: actually it works. It's my JMongoBrowser which lied to me !! anyway thanks a lot

Comment: @John - I have updated my answer. There is some funky UUID and possibly endianness oddities that make it more complex.

Comment: omg that's weird. When I use your ToGuid's method, I have the same Guid I see in my JMongoBrowser. But when I query in C# my mongodb, it returns the value of the "new Guid(Convert.FromBase64String(jsonUuid)). I don't understand the difference ? Can you explain in more detail your answer?

Comment: @John - I have updated my answer. I can 't explain it all although I know it's related to a) the GUID format (see wikipedia) and to underlying computers/OS/technology that may encode integers using a different endiannness (see wikipedia also). Are you using only Windows/.NET or other technologies, OS?

Comment: I use windows/.NET with mongoDB. By the way, thanks for your clarifications. I'll try to find some resource on the web on this subject. It may be interesting to know the difference between uud, guid, base64 etc... and why to choose one instead another etc...

Comment: By the way, how can I convert back my base64 to Guid ?

Comment: I found it. Its return Convert.ToBase64String(id.ToByteArray());